# Scheduler Module shows blank in Sugarcrm CE

Tags: scheduler, sugarcrm

Scheduler Module shows blank in Sugarcrm CE.
There is no error has been logged, switch to Development mode to test also. 
Compare the files aswell. No missing files.
Already ran few times Quick Repair from Admin panel...

Can tell me how to fix/debug this issue?
And this is only happen on Scheduler module... so strange!!
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You say no error logged, did you check both the SugarCRM error log and the PHP log? Can you set PHP's display_errors=On and see if anything comes up?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are someone was customizing a scheduled task and there was a logic error.  That will cause the Schedule Screen to show up blank.